# Splitting git bundle file

Tags: git, git-bundle

Is there any way to split a git bundle file? In say, repo.bundle1 and repo.bundle2, each containing half of the repo. The portable bundle is too large in size for transfer.

How else could I approach this assuming the maximum size allowed for transfer cannot be altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundles can be incremental.

They can't have dangling commits, so there is a bit of a game you have to play if you want to incrementally bundle an existing branch.

They have to be applied "in order" so that as you apply a bundle, its root commits' parents are available to latch onto.  (There may be a way to get around this with shallow repos, but if you're trying to ultimately reconstruct the entire repo then you won't want to worry about that.)

And of course if any single commit is too large (e.g. due to commit of a very large file) that will be a problem.

Say you have

```
       x -- x -- x <--(branch1)
      /
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J <--(master)
                \      /
                 o -- o <--(branch2)
```

And say you want to break this into bundles of no more than 3 commits.  So let's start at the root.  We're going to progressively move the `master` branch, so let's keep track of its current position.

```
git checkout master
git tag real_master
```

Now we look up the SHA ID for `C` (or find some other name that refers to `C`, such as in this case `master~7`) and then

```
git reset --hard master~7
```

Note that I'm using hard resets; that's probably not necessary, but I'm making the assumption that you can do this from a repo with a clean work tree, and in that case doing hard resets keeps everything in nice, simple states (as I see it, anyway).

We're ready to create our first bundle

```
git bundle create 0.bundle master
```

This bundle includes `B`, which is the root for `branch1`, so we can bundle up `branch1` now.

```
git bundle create 1.bundle master..branch1
```

This is equivalent to

```
git bundle create 1.bundle ^master branch1
```

Either way, we're saying to assume that the receiving repo already has the ocmmits reachable from `master`, so *only* the `x` commits will be placed in this bundle.

It might seem like `D`, `E`, `F` is the next logical step; but `F` depends on the `o` commits in `brnach2`.  So really the next logical thing would be to bundle `branch2` along with `D`.  Since we still have `master` at `C` we can say

```
git bundle create 2.bundle master..branch2
```

Now we need to move `master` to `G` so that we can bundle `E`, `F`, and `G`.  Make sure we're on `master` and

```
git reset --hard real_master~3
git bundle create 3.bundle ^branch2 ^master~3 master
```

Here I'm noting that both older mainline history and `branch2` history are reachable from `master` (by way of the merge at `F`), but since they're both already bundled I exclude both of them.

Finally,

```
git reset --hard real_master
git tag -d real_master
git bundle create 4.bundle master~3..master
```

In practice you probably would use more than 3 commits per bundle.  If you have a side-branch that's too big on its own, you can break it up using the same technique we used to segment `master` in this example.

Now you can transfer these independently, and fetch (or pull) from them in order to reconstruct the repo on the other end.

**UPATES**

Two additional notes:

---

First, as compared to ElpieKay's suggestion to use `dd` and `cat`, the above approach has pros and cons.

It only relies on git itself (though the utilities needed for the `dd`/`cat` approach typically ship with git).

The individual bundle files are each useful by themselves, whereas if you segment the file with `dd` you have to reconstruct all the parts to be sure you have a usable bundle.  This also means you could save the bundles and combine them with additional bundles you create later (as more changes happen); but that would only matter if you need to create another new remote repo from scratch at that point.

Actually just shipping incremental changes back and forth, where both sides already have a common baseline of commits, is the basic use case for bundles.  So you might decide to use the `dd`/`cat` approach to initially create the remote repo, then use incremental bundles for subsequent sharing of updates.

The biggest advantages of the `dd`/`cat` approach is that it's *very* rote / scriptable (i.e. simple assuming the tools are on hand), whereas you have to think about how to partition up the commits for the above approach; and also the `dd` approach can split a single, obnoxiously large commit if it turns out to be one.

---

I also forgot to mention initially, that you can list multiple branches to be included in a bundle.  So for example if your threshold were more like 8 commits per bundles, you could

1) Move `master` to `E`

2) bundle `master` and `branch1` as 0.bundle

3) Move `master` back to `J`

4) bundle `master` excluding `master~5` as 1.bundle

and be done.

Answer (score 1):

The command `dd` can split a file into multiple parts. `cat` can combine the parts back into a whole.

Suppose we find that `repo.bundle` is 1466712k, about 1.4g, throught `du repo.bundle`. And suppose the limit is 1g. We can split `repo.bundle` into 2 files, one is 700m and the other is a bit over 700m, so that they can be transferred.

```
dd if=repo.bundle bs=1048576 count=700 skip=0 of=repo.bundle1
dd if=repo.bundle bs=1048576 skip=700 of=repo.bundle2
```

The unit of `bs` is byte so `1048576` is `1m`. `700` means 700 blocks. `skip` is the number of blocks to skip. So the first `dd` writes the first 700*1048576 bytes of `repo.bundle` into `repo.bundle1` and the second `dd` skips the first 700*1048576 and then writes the rest into `repo.bundle2`.

After these two files are transferred to another machine, use `cat` to combine them:

```
cat repo.bundle1 repo.bundle2 > repo.bundle
```

Note that the sequence of the files after `cat` is important. We can use `md5sum` to check if the combined `repo.bundle` is the same with the origin. If two files are still too big, we can split the origin file into more parts. Be careful with `skip` of each `dd`.

`dd`, `cat`, `du`, `md5sum` are also available in `git-bash`.